# Как обрабатывать получение SMS

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, sms, android-permissions

Пытаюсь сделать приложение которое при принятии нового СМС телефоном однократно отправит через блютуз фиксированную строку. Вопрос в следующем как зафиксировать факт получения смс телефоном при этом не меняя его статус на прочитанное. П.С.: Содержимое СМС не важно. В сети находил много примеров отправки и чтения смс, но это вроде как не то.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего нужно добавить permission в

**AndroidManifest.xml**

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />`

Также нужно описать **Receiver** для обработки события описанного выше

```
<receiver android:name="SMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**SMSReceiver**

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          //YOUR_LOGIC_HERE!!
    }
}
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что //YOUR_LOGIC_HERE!! это тот код который должен выполнится? в моем случае это: String GO = "1"; и код не выполняется.

Comment: Какая версия android? если больше 21 то нужно сначала запросить разрешение на чтение sms, и только после этого все отработает

Comment: на api>20 с смс может работать только одна программа, назначенная в системе клиентом смс

Comment: Версия андроид 6 и выше

Comment: Разрешение включил в настройках телефона

Comment: Если используется hangout в телефоне нужно попробовать отключить поддержку СМС, и попробовать снова на девайсе

Comment: hangout не используется

Comment: Попробуй на другом девайсе, возможно проблема в прошивке! Если какой-нибудь "китаец"  скорее всего система глушит этот broadcast

Comment: Телефон Lenovo, таже проблема сохраняется на эмуляторе.